# Unable to lock screen orientation to portrait only in xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4

In xcode 4 I am unable to lock the screen orientation to only portrait even though I have portrait selected only. How to I do this programmatically?

```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

this code works in a new blank project

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each view controller (or just the parent), implement `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` Set the default orientation to portrait and then do:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}
```

Alternately, you can do:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

which will allow a rotation to portrait but not away from it.

Comment: It seems that its stuck to the settings that I started the project with. I made a new blank app and it works but not in my existing app!!! It's really annoying!

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer did not work for me either. This did:

In the properties file for your app (YOURAPPNAME-Info.plist), located in the "supporting files" group, there is an array called "Supported interface orientations". Remove both landscape values from the array and your app will be locked in portrait orientation.